# using unlist() for multiple layer list and result not merge a column

Tags: r, list, lapply

How do I use `unlist()` or other function on `bunnyConvexlhull`,the result is 3 column (ex:`bunnyConvexlhull[[1]]`)?

I want to display such as:

```
a <- bunnyConvexlhull[[1]] #row:390 col:3
b <- bunnyConvexlhull[[2]] #row:212 col:3
```

for result, I want to get data a+b+... is row:1170+636+..., col:3

but my result is all values merge into just one column(fail result).

Thanks!!

```
library("onion")
library("geometry")
library("rgl")

data(bunny)
bunny <- as.data.frame(bunny)
maxZ <- max(bunny[,3]) #> 0.0587997
minZ <- min(bunny[,3]) #> -0.0618736
interval <- (maxZ-minZ)/0.01 #interval:0.01
bunnySlices <- split(bunny, ggplot2::cut_interval(bunny[,3], interval))
bunnyConvexlhull <- lapply(bunnySlices, function(x) convhulln(x))

a <- bunnyConvexlhull[[1]] #row:390 col:3
b <- bunnyConvexlhull[[2]] #row:212 col:3

bunnyConvexlhull[[1]] #3 column
result <- data.frame(unlist(bunnyConvexlhull)) #1 column
```

I try this, but just get the fist value.

```
lapply(bunnyConvexlhull, `[[`, c(1))
```

Comment: Do you want to rbind? `do.call(rbind, bunnyConvexlhull)`

Comment: It's a pity that I noticed this now. This way solved my question, thanks!